# Change Subversive repository label

Tags: eclipse, subversive

When you link project to a repository a wizard like this appears:

[image]

There you can edit the repository label. My question is how can I change that label after I've closed that window ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `SVN Repositories` view, open the context menu of your repository and select `Location Properties...`.

This will open the `Edit Repository Location` dialog where you can change the repository label.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reopen this dialog again via Location Properties.

Switch to the SVN Exploring perspective via:

```
Window -> Open Perspective -> SVN Exploring Perspective
```

and afterwards:

```
Rightclick on the repository -> Location properties -> Use a custom label
```

[Location Properties...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKtIa.jpg)